# Touch sensor with a CR2032 battery and a transistor

Tags: led

I'm not an electronics engineer but I have a question that may look strange to a specialist:

Can I make a touch sensor that lights a LED using a CR2032 battery?

I tried to use [this](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-build-a-touch-sensor-circuit) circuit without the resistances and with a different power source but the LED is not at full power.

Thank you.

Comment: Power LED also from battery?

Comment: What sort of LED are you trying to power?  CR2032 cells are only designed to produce a very small current.

Comment: Yes, the LED is powered from the CR2032 and this battery can power the LED alone, but I'm not sure if it can also power a touch sensor. The led is a regular led, 5mm, 20mA.

Comment: A few mA (5-10 mA) for a few seconds at a time won't kill a CR2032 too fast. My LED watch eats maybe 2 a year. Running the LED continuously would be a different matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could play with something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqPKLH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The CR2032 has enough internal resistance that the LED does not burn out.

There's a good chance M1 could be damaged by touching the gate but if you touch the (-) battery terminal first it should work for a while.

Eventually the gate leakage will cause the LED to turn on or off (by itself) after some time.